# como puedo lograr que realice la navegacion correctamente?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-router-dom

en esta función se supone que debe validar que rol tiene el usuario para así renderizar uno u otro componente

```
function Main() {
    
  
    useEffect(() => {
      checkAuth();
    }, []);
  
    const checkAuth = async () => {
      const user = await getUser();
      let screen = ``
      
      if(user.data.role === 'admin'){
      screen = `adminHome`
      console.log('USER.ADMIN', user.data)
      }else{
      screen = `home`
      console.log('USER', user.data)
      }
      
      console.log(screen)
      
      return screen
    };

    const navigator = useNavigation(); 
    
    
  }
  
  export default Main;
```

en principio al iniciar la aplicación todo parece correcto pero al desloguearse y volver a hacerlo no redirige a ninguna de las dos pantallas y se queda en Main.

aquí muestro cómo están diseñadas las rutas:

(los imports si estan solo que no los pongo para que me permita subir la pregunta)

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();



export default function App() {
  
  return (
    <RecoilRoot>
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
            
            <Stack.Screen name="main" component={Main} />
            
            <Stack.Screen name='adminHome' component={AdminHome} options={{
              headerLeft: () => null

            }}
            />

            <Stack.Screen name="home" component={HomePage} options={{
              headerLeft: () => null
              
            }}
              />
            
            <Stack.Screen name="login" component={Login}  options={{
              title: 'Login'
              }}          
              />
            <Stack.Screen name="register" component={Register}  options={{
              title: 'Register'
              }}          
              />

            <Stack.Screen name="routines" component={Routines}  options={{
              animation: 'slide_from_right',
              title: 'Routine'
            }}

            />
            
            <Stack.Screen name="editProfile" component={EditProfile}  options={{
              animation: 'slide_from_right',
              title: 'editProfile'
            }}

            />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    </RecoilRoot>
  );
}
```

aquí muestro como se obtiene el usuario en la funcion getUser() que se ejecuta en Main al entrar

```
const API_URL = "https://columbus-app.vercel.app"


export const getUser = async () => {
  try {
      const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
      const user = await fetch(`${API_URL}/auth/loged`, {
        method:'GET',
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:19006',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,  
        },
      }).then((res) => res.json());
      AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
      return user;
    } catch ({error}) {
      console.error(error);
      return false;
    }
  };
```

una vez visto todo esto no puedo encontrar la solucion al problema, agradezco su ayuda en lo que puedan